# I am using LoginRequiredMixin in Django. If I type the url in search bar it shows the page without being logged in

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I am using LoginRequiredMixin in a django class view **AdCreateView** which is binded to the url /create. When I type the whole url it goes to the page even if I'm logged out but if I click on the create button from anywhere else on the site it redirects to the login page.

I would like for it to redirect to the login page in both cases.

My urls.py

```
    path('', AdListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('create/', AdCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
```

views.py

```
class AdCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    template_name = 'ads/ad_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('ads:list')

    def get(self, request, pk=None):
        form = CreateForm()
        ctx = {'form': form}
        return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)

    def post(self, request, pk=None):
        form = CreateForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)

        if not form.is_valid():
            ctx = {'form': form}
            return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)

        # Add owner to the model before saving
        pic = form.save(commit=False)
        pic.owner = self.request.user
        pic.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return redirect(self.success_url)
```

Comment: Please also add the `AdListView` source code. Make sure it inherits from the `LoginRequiredMixin` as well

Comment: using LoginRequiredMixin on AdListView would make it so that only logged in users can see it. I don't want to do that. I want everyone to see the ads without having to login.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't get the question for some reason =) In this case, the behaviour is certainly weird...